# Groovy: how to concatenate string constants in annotation?

Tags: groovy

In java I can write `@SomeAnnotation("abc"+"cd")`. When I do the same in groovy i got compilation error 'expected ... to be an inline constant'. how can i concatenate string constants inside annotations in groovy?

Comment: You can't. This must be a compile time constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't because this expression isn't a compile time constant in Groovy.

You have a few options here

- Declare a plain Java interface with constants and use it from Groovy

  ```
  @SomeAnnotation(Constants.MY_CONST)
  ```
- If you can change source code of annotation you can try using [closure annotation parameters](http://groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html#_closure_annotation_parameters)
- You can also play with [compile-time AST transformations](http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_compile_time_metaprogramming) here to achieve your goal in a dirty way. (Very probably you don't want to play with AST)

Inability to use expressions like `'aaa' + 'bbb'` isn't the only problem, you can see errors like `Attribute 'value' should have type 'java.lang.String'; but found type 'java.lang.Object'` even with compile-time expressions. Here is a related issue [GROOVY-3278](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-3278) with possible workarounds.